# always getting suspicious request on Pluralsight assessment

Tags: support, error-message, pluralsight-iq, suspicious-request

Previously I was successfully able to add Plurasight ID Assessment skill IQ.
But now when trying to add new skill always getting error:

> Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Stack Overflow, please return to the previous page and try again.

Even I trying by re-login to both Stackoverflow $ Pluralsight, restart Mac, clear cookies.

Comment: Does anyone get solutions?

Comment: Finally solved, logout from StackOverflow including all domains on all devices. Also logout from Plurasight. Then login to Pluralsight and chose skill IQ to share